# underscore js _grouby Browser Difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm seeing some strange behavior with the order in which a select's optgroups and options are being rendered. I have some data that is used to build optgroup in a select and then options using the underscore js _grouby function. Firefox is rendering the data the way I ordered the json, Chrome and IE are displaying it in reverse order.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Netmonster/8Tx6H/4/)

Html:

```
 <select name="dropdownlist" id="dropdownlist">
   <option value="All">All</option>
 </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var dataresults = [{"MonthName":"April","Month":4,"Year":2014,"Date":"\/Date(1397451600000)\/"},{"MonthName":"January","Month":1,"Year":2014,"Date":"\/Date(1388556000000)\/"},{"MonthName":"November","Month":11,"Year":2013,"Date":"\/Date(1384322400000)\/"},{"MonthName":"July","Month":7,"Year":2013,"Date":"\/Date(1373864400000)\/"}];

 BindYearDropDown(dataresults);

 function BindYearDropDown(data)
    {
        var groupData = _.groupBy(data, function (obj) {
            return obj.Year;
        });

        var optGroups = [];
        for (var key in groupData) {
            if (groupData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var optGroup = $("<optgroup></optgroup>");
                optGroup.attr("label", key);
                optGroup.attr("id", key);
                var currentGroup = groupData[key];
                for (var i = 0; i < currentGroup.length; i++) {
                    $("<option />").attr("value", currentGroup[i].Month).html(currentGroup[i].MonthName).appendTo(optGroup);
                }
                optGroups.push(optGroup);
            }
        }
        //optGroups.reverse();
        for (var i = 0; i < optGroups.length; i++) {
            $('#dropdownlist').append(optGroups[i]);
        }
    };
```

FireFox Results: (This is how I would like the data displayed)

[image: FireFox Results]

Chrome Results:

[image: Chrome Results:]

IE11 Results:

[image: IE11 Results:]

Thanks in advance,

KC

Comment: JavaScript objects [are not ordered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22845062/479863). You're using the wrong data structure, if you need things in a specific order then you **must** use an array and sort that array as needed. `_.groupBy` returns an Object, not an array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Does FF handle JS objects differently than the other browsers? My real service that returns the data takes a sort direction in as a parm and FF changes based of the base on the asc, or desc returned data..

Comment: @KC. In this post, https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164, it shows the even object order is OS dependent. Chrome on Linux will produce different results compared to Chrome on Winows! For now, I guess, you're stuck with ordering the results yourself.

Comment: AFAIK most browsers use insertion order but that's not guaranteed. Don't depend on empirical "what does this browser do?" checks, start with the specifications and adjust to work around browser problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to work with the data in the structure you provided, you can create a list of years and then sort that. Otherwise, I recommend what @mu is too short suggested. [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Tx6H/6/)

```
/* reusable descending sort function */
function sortDescending(value) {
  return value * -1;
};

     ...
     var groupData = _.groupBy(data, function (obj) {
         return obj.Year;
     });

     /* Sort the years in descending order */
     var years = _.sortBy(_.keys(groupData), sortDescending);

     var optGroups = [];
     for (var index in years) {
         var key = years[index];
     ...
```