# lodash sortBy then groupBy, is order maintained?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I'm having trouble figuring out from the lodash documentation if my assumption about sorting and grouping is correct.

If I use sortBy, then use groupBy, do the arrays produced by groupBy maintain the sort order of items?

For example, say I have the following array:

```
var testArray = [[5,6],[1,3],[5,4],[5,1]]
```

And I would like to group these by their first element, but also have them sorted by their second element within these groups. So, in lodash I assume I can do the following:

```
_.chain(testArray)
  .sortBy(function (item) { return item[1]; })
  .groupBy(function (item) { return item[0]; })
  .value()
```

Which ends up producing what I would expect it to:

```
{
  1: [[1,3]]
  5: [[5,1],[5,4],[5,6]]
}
```

Is this just coincidence? Is there anything about how sortBy and groupBy work that ensures this ordering of the grouped arrays? The documentation says that sortBy is a stable sort, does that in the same way apply to groupBy? Is there any reason I should not assume this will work every time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [current implementation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/e914b83a1b97345fbd8cb68197caf7380bea331d/vendor/underscore/underscore.js#L384) of `_.groupBy` is:

```
// An internal function used for aggregate "group by" operations.
var group = function(behavior) {
  return function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    var result = {};
    iteratee = cb(iteratee, context);
    _.each(obj, function(value, index) {
      var key = iteratee(value, index, obj);
      behavior(result, value, key);
    });
    return result;
  };
};

// Groups the object's values by a criterion. Pass either a string attribute
// to group by, or a function that returns the criterion.
_.groupBy = group(function(result, value, key) {
  if (_.has(result, key)) result[key].push(value); else result[key] = [value];
});
```

Basically it iterates through each of the items in the collection in order (if the collection is array-like, which it would be after a `sortBy`), and pushes them to an array based on their key value.

So yes, I'm not sure if this is an "official" characteristic of `_.groupBy`, but it does preserve the order of array-like collections, and that's probably unlikely to change.

Comment: So the sub-items within groups would retain their original ordering, but the grouped key ordering may change, because they are object properties.

Answer (score 24):

It's not. Here's example, where order is not retained:

```
const data = [
  {
    item: 'item1',
    group: 'g2'
  },   {
    item: 'item2',
    group: 'g3'
  },   {
    item: 'item3',
    group: 'g1'
  },   {
    item: 'item4',
    group: 'g2'
  },   {
    item: 'item5',
    group: 'g3'
  }
]

const groupedItems = _(data).groupBy(item => item.group).value()
```

In this case one would expect that group order would be: g2, g3, g1 - reality is that they are sorted g1, g2, g3.

You can re-sort them with original array though.

```
const groupedItems = _(data)
  .groupBy(item => item.group)
  .sortBy(group => data.indexOf(group[0]))
  .value()
```

This will ensure original order of items.

Comment: This is pure gold: `.sortBy(group => data.indexOf(group[0]))` .
Saved me an hour in trying to get the damn thing working!

Comment: Maybe there was a change to the library, but your first examples output comes out in the group order expected. I'm using lodash v4.17.15

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is about. Of course the groups are not sorted, because object properties are not sorted (the `groupBy` gives an object, not an array!). The question is about the order inside each group, not about the order of the groups.

Comment: Instead of using `data.indexOf(group[0])` for resorting, we can also keep track of the index of the item in the initial list. E.g.: `_.chain([6.1, 4.2, 6.3]).map((v, initialIndex) => ({initialIndex, v})).groupBy(({v}) => Math.floor(v)).values().sortBy((group) => group[0].initialIndex).map((group) => group.map(({v}) => v)).value()`

Answer (score 1):

Function groupBy returns object. Object doesn't save property order.
[Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

But group arrays saves order, because thay are added with push function.

Comment: My question was about the ordering of the resulting arrays, not the parent object produced by `groupBy`.

Comment: Update a little my answer. Just I had trouble with object property order and I decided to write this.