# Lodash groupBy() Method should be in same order as original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, lodash

> I'm working on an array using groupBy lodash method, here the
> original array order does not exist on performing groupBy, is the any
> way to regain it after groupBy()

```
  const groupBy from "groupBy/lodash";

const mockData = [
 { groupId:"44", groupName:"mno",   },
 { groupId:"45", groupName:"pqr"  },
 { groupId:"40", groupName:"abc"  },
 { groupId:"41", groupName:"def"  },
]
const filteredArray = mockData.filter(item =>....); //logic to filter based on few parameters
const newArray = groupBy(filteredArray, "groupId");
console.log(newArray);

 result - {
 40: [{ groupId:"40", groupName:"abc"  }],
 41: [{ groupId:"41", groupName:"def"  }],
 44: [{ groupId:"44", groupName:"mno"  }],
 45: [{ groupId:"45", groupName:"pqr"  }],
}

expected - {
    44: [{ groupId:"44", groupName:"mno",   }],
    45: [{ groupId:"45", groupName:"pqr"  }],
    40: [{ groupId:"40", groupName:"abc"  }],
    41 [{ groupId:"41", groupName:"def"  }],
    }
```

Comment: since final ressult is object. does order matter

Comment: yes it should be same order as array order, irrespective of object or array type

Comment: i meant in object you cannot guarantee order

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860526/lodash-sortby-then-groupby-is-order-maintained

Comment: if you need an array as final result you can preserve order

Answer (score 0):

My guess, the groupBy method is **sorting/grouping** the array using **groupId**.

Can you clarify this question, are you saying the mockData order is diff and newArray order is diff. If so, then it is groupedBy groupId otherwise its mutating the array.

Comment: groupBy() will perform both grouping and sorting, then is there any way I can regain the original order on the result of groupBy method,

Answer (score 0):

The `_.groupBy()` function creates an object. You are grouping by the `id`, and the ids are integers in a string form. ES6 traversal order rules order the integer properties by their value (ascending) - see this [article](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#integer-indices). In your case, the groups are sorted by the `id` integer value.

Since `_.groupBy()` doesn't actually sort the keys, nor can you sort object's integer keys explicitly, you'll need to use another structure that preserves the order - a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
const groupByToMap = (arr, predicate) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
    const key = predicate(o)
    
    if(!acc.has(key)) acc.set(key, [])
  
    acc.get(key).push(o)
  
    return acc
  }, new Map())

const mockData = [{ groupId:"44", groupName:"mno" }, { groupId:"45", groupName:"pqr"  },  { groupId:"40", groupName:"abc"  }, { groupId:"41", groupName:"def"  }]

const result = groupByToMap(mockData, o => o.groupId)

// !!! look at the browser's console (the snippet's would display an empty object) !!!
console.log(result) 

// when converting to an object the keys would be reordered by their integer value
console.log(Object.fromEntries(result))
```

Comment: main issue itself is ordering as per original order

Comment: I know. I explain and demonstrate why it can't be done in an object. However, it can be done with a Map. Read my answer and review the code. Open the *browser's* console to see the order of the Map.