# How to group and sort a nested array and keep the original order based on the first occurrence?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array that is flat and already properly ordered. To display it in the UI, I need to sort it, by the `placeId`, keeping the `placeId` order, as well as the order of elements in the `data` property.

```
const sortedData = [
  { id: 1, placeId: 12 },
  { id: 5, placeId: 12 },
  { id: 8, placeId: 31 },
  { id: 16, placeId: 31 },
  { id: 20, placeId: 45 },
  { id: 22, placeId: 45 },
]
```

```
// maintain order of place as well as data based on first appearance in sortedData
const uiPreparedData = [
  {
    place: 12,
    data: [
      { id: 1, placeId: 12 },
      { id: 5, placeId: 12 },
    ],
  },

  {
    place: 31,
    data: [
      { id: 8, placeId: 31 },
      { id: 16, placeId: 31 },
    ],
  },
  {
    place: 45,
    data: [
      { id: 20, placeId: 45 },
      { id: 22, placeId: 45 },
    ],
  },
]
```

Based on [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860526/lodash-sortby-then-groupby-is-order-maintained) I found the following solution containing `lodash`. However, I cannot apply it to the nested structure of my case.

```
  var uiPreparedData = _.chain(sortedData)
    // Group the elements of Array based on `place` property
    .groupBy("placeId")
    .sortBy((item) => item.indexOf(item[0]))
    // `key` is group's name (place), `value` is the array of objects
    .map((value, key) => ({ place: key, data: value }))
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `sortedArray` is already properly ordered, it seems running your code without `.sortBy` in the lodash chain would already give you the expected result.

However, if I understand the question correctly, you would like to keep the groupBy order based on `placeId` as it is ordered in the `sortedArray` (which is ordered by `id`), correct?  If so, couple corrections to your code:

1. Function passed to `.sortBy` paramater should be `item => sortedData.indexOf(item[0])`
2. Since the `placeId` is the same for each item in `data` array, the `place` property can be equal to the first `placeId` value in the sorted array: `place: value[0].placeId`

Here is an example:

```js
const sortedData = [
  { id: 1, placeId: 12 },
  { id: 5, placeId: 12 },
  { id: 6, placeId: 45 }, // Added to demonstrate order
  { id: 8, placeId: 31 },
  { id: 16, placeId: 31 },
  { id: 20, placeId: 45 },
  { id: 22, placeId: 45 },
]

const uiPreparedData = _.chain(sortedData)
  .groupBy("placeId")
  .sortBy(item => sortedData.indexOf(item[0]))
  .map((value, key) => ({ place: value[0].placeId, data: value }))
  .value()

console.log(uiPreparedData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```